# Get all combinations of items in a list while prohibiting certain items from being together

Tags: python-3.x, python-itertools

Say I have a list as follows:

```
spam = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2']
```

I want to get all possible combinations of items in this list (of lengths from 1 to `len(spam)`) while not letting `A1` in a combination together with `A2`, as well as `B1` with `B2` and `C1` with `C2`.

Expected output:

Combinations of length 1:

```
[('A1'),
 ('A2'),
 ('B1'),
 ('B2'),
 ('C1'),
 ('C2')]
```

Combinations of length 2:

```
[('A1', 'B1'),
 ('A1', 'B2'),
 ('A1', 'C1'),
 ('A1', 'C2'),
 ('A2', 'B1'),
 ('A2', 'B2'),
 ('A2', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'C2'),
 ('B1', 'C1'),
 ('B1', 'C2'),
 ('B2', 'C1'),
 ('B2', 'C2')]
```

Combinations of length 3:

```
[('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A1', 'B1', 'C2'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'C1'),
 ('A1', 'B2', 'C2'),
 ('A2', 'B1', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'B1', 'C2'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C1'),
 ('A2', 'B2', 'C2')]
```

Combinations of length 4 and higher should return an empty list since no combinations of length 4 and higher can possibly avoid inclusion of prohibited combinations.

Then simply gather combinations of different lengths in one list.

While this seems like a simple task, I don't have much ideas on how to implement this, apart from getting all combinations without restrictions first (via `itertools.combinations`) and then setting up a complicated rule to filter out all undesired combinations, which seems tedious. Is there an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can make use of `filter`:
EDIT:

Your question wast clear at first. This is what you are looking for:

```
import itertools, re

filter_fun = lambda x: re.search("(.)\\d.*\\1","".join(x)) is None
def get_combs(lst,here = None):
    if here is None: here = {}
    comb = len(here)+1
    a = [i for i in itertools.combinations(lst,comb) if filter_fun(i)]
    if a==[]: return here
    here.update({comb:a})
    return get_combs(lst,here)

get_combs(spam)
{1: [('A1',), ('A2',), ('B1',), ('B2',), ('C1',), ('C2',)],
 2: [('A1', 'B1'),
  ('A1', 'B2'),
  ('A1', 'C1'),
  ('A1', 'C2'),
  ('A2', 'B1'),
  ('A2', 'B2'),
  ('A2', 'C1'),
  ('A2', 'C2'),
  ('B1', 'C1'),
  ('B1', 'C2'),
  ('B2', 'C1'),
  ('B2', 'C2')],
 3: [('A1', 'B1', 'C1'),
  ('A1', 'B1', 'C2'),
  ('A1', 'B2', 'C1'),
  ('A1', 'B2', 'C2'),
  ('A2', 'B1', 'C1'),
  ('A2', 'B1', 'C2'),
  ('A2', 'B2', 'C1'),
  ('A2', 'B2', 'C2')]}
```

Comment: It fails on lengths other than 2, lengths 3 and above allow inclusion of prohibited combinations.

Comment: @AlwaysRightNeverLeft so if the combination is 3 what should be the result?

Comment: result = [['A1', 'B1', 'C1'], ['A2', 'B1', 'C1'], ['A2', 'B2', 'C1'], ['A2', 'B2', 'C2'], ['A1', 'B2', 'C1'], ['A1', 'B1', 'C2']].

For lengths 4 and above the result should be an empty list since no combinations of length 4 and above can avoid inclusion of prohibited combinations.

Comment: No, I'm not looking for just a product. In this example, I want all combinations of all lengths from 1 to len(spam), i.e. all combinations of length 1 plus all combinations of length 2 plus all combinations of length 3, after which higher lenghts output empty lists. In practice the size of the list can be arbitrarily high, so can be the number of prohibited combinations.

Comment: your first aproach works just fine after edit, I will simply be looping through all c in range(len(spam)).

Answer (score -1):

If each object can be written as ["important part", "number part"], (as in A1 -> ["A", 1]), it would be easier to do what you want, by "concatenating" items that don't share the first item of the list.

Something like:

```
spam = [["A", "1"], ["A", "2"], ["B","1"]]

output = []
for i in range(len(spam)):
  for j in range(i, len(spam)):
    if spam[i][0] != spam[j][0]:
      output+=["".join(spam[i])+"".join(spam[j])]
print(output)
```

Comment: I sort of get the idea, just not sure about the actual implementation, can you provide some pointers?

Comment: While I get this approach, I need to generate combinations of different lengths, not just 2, and extending this loopy approach to work with combinations of arbitrary length seems rather tedious and unpythonic.

Comment: Right, sorry. Didn't understand that it would be for different lengths. Maybe a recursive function? That would maybe calculate all length-2 combinations, and then length-3 which are kind of length-2 combinations calculated with the length-1 ones (which are the initial values), etc?